# Media queries are not reflecting while using Preact

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, media-queries, preact

I am trying to use Preact of my existing application in react

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) 
    {
      .card {
         margin-top: 12px;
     }
      .card-body {
          padding: 12px;
       }
  }
```

But css are not reflecting in Preact it was taking the default styles of website styles.

No specific document found.

Please let me know how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction? CSS is CSS, whatever JS UI lib you're using has no bearing or effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a question about `preact-cli`, not Preact itself.

If so, I'd guess the CSS file is being treated as a CSS Module, which will prefix any classNames (and requires reflecting this in your source). As a workaround, try:

```
:global {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) 
  {
    .card {
      margin-top: 12px;
    }
    .card-body {
      padding: 12px;
    }
  }
}
```